# Как сохранить с браузера на пк jar файл?

Tags: jar

Есть сайт с виртуальными лабораторными работами - http://teachmen.ru/work/atomic/atomic.php . Мне очень нужно как-то выдрать оттуда лабораторную "атомный реактор", что бы я могла ее просто запускать на пк. Это возможно?? Большое спасибо)

Comment: Даша, Вам можно доверять? Эта ссылка не ловушка? Ведь если jar лежит в общем доступе, то его сохранение через браузер ничем не отличается от сохранения других файлов.

Comment: @Sergey нет) это сайт лабораторных робот с физики)) какие там могут быть ловушки) проверьте его через Virus Total если будет желание)  И он там не лежит файлом для скачивания, оно работает в браузере.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать копию сайта. Раньше знаю была такая прога teleportpro

Comment: @Sergey спасибо) сейчас попробую

Comment: там используется апплет. у вас он работает?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman В ie11 java всё ещё работает например.

Comment: @Sergey она не только в нем работает. я спрашивал ТС. так как думаю, что там XY проблема.